# How do I apply jquery animation to my popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a created a simple popup with jquery, basically if a button is pressed,  a div's 'display' changes from 'none' to 'block' in css and displays an overlay to make the background darker.

See my code:

```
function div_show() {
    $("#login").css({display:'block'});
    $("#overlay").css({background:'#000'});
    $("#overlay").css({zIndex:'2'});
}
//Function to Hide Popup
function div_hide(){
    $("#login").css({display:'none'});
    $("#overlay").css({background:'none'});
    $("#overlay").css({zIndex:'-1'});
}
```

And the popup itself (html) if handy:

```
 <div id="overlay"></div>

    <button onClick="div_show()">Click me</button>

    <div id="login">
            <div id="loginpopup">
                stuff
            </div> 
    </div>
```

I want to have an animation, like fading, when this popup shows, but i haven't managed it. I tried adding `$("#login").fadeIn();` to the 'div_open()' function, but that doesn't work obviously.

I hope someone can help me.

Many thanks,

Paul

Comment: instead of `$("#login").css({display:'block'});` try `$("#login").fadeIn();`. Same in hide `$("#login").fadeOut();`

Comment: @juanpastas This is indeed a good, working way. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the jQuery `.show()` and `.hide()` methods as referenced [here](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [here](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

You can then easily add animations, using jQuery's api.

```
 $( "#login" ).show( "slow", function() {
      // Animation complete.
 });
```

If you are alternating the showing and hiding, it might be easier to use the `.toggle()` function referenced [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)